# how make own gitian-sigs end detached sigs?

Tags: hash, signature, bitcoin-core-development, altcoin-development, gitian

How make own gitian-sigs end detached-sigs. I cannot find any useful info. Where i try see it's always start with "you  already have .assert and .sig . but how they create ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instructions for setting up a Gitian building environment are available at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/gitian-building.md. Instructions for performing the gitian builds for releases are available here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-process.md

Comment: I dint no see command to create own .assets ,this method say's how to create new sig from exist. But i want create only own.

Comment: The .asset files are created by the gbuild commands. There is no command which explicitly has .asset in it.

Comment: but what command add to build file for create asset's end then make sig with gpg :/ For sig assests with gpg need fist it create but gitian builder not create it if assets not exist

Comment: You need to first build the binaries. You do that with the commands that begin with `./bin/gbuild`. That command will also create the `.assert` files in your gitian.sigs directory. Then you sign those files with GPG. It will create those files; this is the exact process used for making the releases and their gitian sigs.